# Google Spreadsheet script (if and checkboxes)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function MyFunction() {
  for(x=4;x<=45;x++)
  {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(x, 7).getValue();
    var box = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(x, 3).getValue();
    var box2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(x, 4).getValue();

    if(box == "TRUE" && box2 == "TRUE")
      var sum = sheet+50;
    else if(box == "TRUE" && box2 == "FALSE")
      var sum = sheet+20;
    else if(box == "FALSE" && box2 == "TRUE")
      var sum = sheet+30;
    else
      var sum = sheet;

    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(x, 16).setValue(sum);  
  }
}
```

columns 3 and 4 contain checkBoxes the column 7 contain integer values, the idea is to add +50 if both checkBoxes on its row are checked, +20 if only the first one is checked, +30 if the second one is checked and keep the integer column value if none is checked.

Comment: Can I ask you about your current issue?

Comment: it always gets to the point (else var sum = sheet;) and just type again the same numeric value, somehow it ignores all other parameters.

Comment: Checkboxes can have any values for their checked and unchecked states. This may be the Boolean `true` or `false`, string values like `"yes"` or `"no"`, etc. Consider using the `Range#isChecked` method instead of making assumptions about the values. Also consider rewriting your code entirely, to avoid the extremely inefficient per-cell access pattern you are using.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed the modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the values from the columns "C", "D" and "G".

  - The columns "C" and "D" are the checkboxes.
  - The column "G" is the numbers.
- You want to achieve the following conditions.

  - When the columns "C" and "D" are `true` and `true`, you want to add `50` to the value of column "G".
  - When the columns "C" and "D" are `true` and `false`, you want to add `20` to the value of column "G".
  - When the columns "C" and "D" are `false` and `true`, you want to add `30` to the value of column "G".
  - When the columns "C" and "D" are `false` and `false`, you want to use the value of column "G".
- You want to put the result values to the column "P".
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.
- Your issue is that `sum` is always `sheet` which is the value of the column "G".

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, your script is modified.

#### Modification point:

- When the value from a checkbox is retrieved with `getValue()`, the value is the boolean type. In your script, the string values of `TRUE` and `FALSE` are used at the if statement. By this, `var sum = sheet;` is always run. I think that this is the reason of your issue.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

From:

```
if(box == "TRUE" && box2 == "TRUE")
  var sum = sheet+50;
else if(box == "TRUE" && box2 == "FALSE")
  var sum = sheet+20;
else if(box == "FALSE" && box2 == "TRUE")
  var sum = sheet+30;
else
  var sum = sheet;
```

To:

```
var sum = sheet;
if(box === true && box2 === true)
  sum = sheet+50;
else if(box === true && box2 === false)
  sum = sheet+20;
else if(box === false && box2 === true)
  sum = sheet+30;
```

#### Note:

- At Google Apps Script, even when the variable of `sum` is declared in the if statement, `sum` can be retrieved at the outside of the if statement. So the script works. But from the scope of variable, I recommend to declare the variable of `sum` at the out of the if statement like above modified script.

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, your goal is achieved by reducing the process cost from your script. In this case, the values  from the columns "C" to "G" are retrieved with `getValues()`, and the retrieved values are processed. Then, the result values are put to the column "P" with `setValues()`. In your situation, when `getValues()`, `setValues()` and `map()` are used instead of `getValue()`, `setValue()` and the for loop, the process cost can be reduced. [Ref1](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4), [Ref2](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/848aeafaac1ec676900bb78e3ce220b6)

#### Modified script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var values = sheet.getRange("C4:G45").getValues();
  var numbers = values.map(function([c, d,,,g]) {return [
    (c === true && d === true) ? g + 50 :
    (c === true && d === false) ? g + 20 :
    (c === false && d === true) ? g + 30 : g
  ]});
  sheet.getRange(4, 16, numbers.length, 1).setValues(numbers);
}
```

### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [Benchmark: Reading and Writing Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)
- [Benchmark: Loop for Array Processing using Google Apps Script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/848aeafaac1ec676900bb78e3ce220b6)
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: You might want to link to a reference for array destructuring as well. I don't know that many realize that it is supported in Apps Script, even for the Rhino runtime.

Comment: @tehhowch Thank you for your comment. I added it.

Comment: you guys are amazing, thanks for the links and the effort, I'm trying to learn more about the spreadsheets scripts, and this answer was a solid 10/10, appreciate the help.